# Error when I used GROUP_CONCAT on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my code worked good , but when i add

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<a href='index.php?id=", awards_user.userid, "'>", awards_user.username, "</a>")) AS userlist
```

to get users-id with username , show me error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING [in this line]

```
SELECT awards.name as name, awards.link as link, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username) AS username,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.userid) AS userid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<a href='index.php?id=", awards_user.userid, "'>", awards_user.username, "</a>")) AS userlist
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   where awards.forumid = '".$_REQUEST['forumid']."'
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link
```

Comment: same error on same line , thnx

Comment: You need to go learn the basics of PHP string handling and escaping.

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the double quotes.

Comment: `'".$_REQUEST['forumid']."'` that's not Cause of the problem , the error on line `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<a href='index.php?id=", awards_user.userid, "'>", awards_user.username, "</a>")) AS userlist
`

Comment: thnx all ,Found to solve the problem

Comment: yeah i do it already , But stackoverflow.com should wait a minute to check the answer , thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape double quotes `"` with backslash `\` otherwise php will understand this as the end of the string :

```
$sql = "SELECT awards.name as name
             , awards.link as link
             , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username) AS username
             , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.userid) AS userid
             , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(\"<a href='index.php?id=\", awards_user.userid, \"'>\"
             , awards_user.username, \"</a>\")) AS userlist
        FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
        WHERE awards.forumid = '" . $_REQUEST['forumid'] . "'
        GROUP BY awards.awardid
               , awards.name
               , awards.link";
```

Answer (score 0):

The escaping of quotes is an issue. So why not use [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like this.

```
$formid = $_REQUEST['forumid'];

$query = <<<EOT
SELECT awards.name as name, awards.link as link, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username) AS username,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.userid) AS userid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<a href='index.php?id=", awards_user.userid, "'>", awards_user.username, "</a>")) AS userlist
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   where awards.forumid = '$formid'
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link
EOT;
```

The idea is heredoc syntax allows for a full string with string replacement & without having to worry about escaping quotes. Or knowing that you can set variables for `"<a href='index.php?id="`, `'>` and `</a>` like this:

```
$formid = $_REQUEST['forumid'];

$id_link_1 = "<a href='index.php?id=";
$id_link_2 = "'>";
$id_link_3 = "</a>";

$query = <<<EOT
SELECT awards.name as name, awards.link as link, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username) AS username,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.userid) AS userid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT($id_link_1, awards_user.userid, $id_link_2, awards_user.username, $id_link_3)) AS userlist
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   where awards.forumid = '$formid'
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link
EOT;
```

Comment: thnx so much , i Found to solve the problem , but i will try your code and I'll take care you observe